# C# JSON .NET deserialize with JsonObjects in another object

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I've created a PHP interface that connects to a database, by encoding JSON in PHP and decoding it on the C# using JSON .NET.
Everything has worked fine so far.
I have a few classes that I use, which I all created to be used with JSON .NET

```js
{
  "ReceptId": "1",
  "Naam": "Rijst met ragout",
  "GramPerPersoon": "280",
  "Type": "Eten",
  "Instructies": [
    "Maak rijst warm",
    "Doe ragout op de rijst"
  ],
  "Benodigdheden": [{
    "Hoeveelheid": "70",
    "Eenheid": "gram",
    "Ingredient": {
      "Ingredient_id": "1",
      "Naam": "Rijst",
      "Beschrijving": "Rijst behoort zoals alle granen tot de grassenfamilie. Rijst is het belangrijkste voedsel voor een groot deel van de wereldbevolking, vooral in de warmere streken.",
      "Energie": "355",
      "Vetten": "0.5",
      "VerzadigdeVetten": "0.2",
      "KoolHydraten": "79",
      "Eiwitten": "7.5"
    }
  }, {
    "Hoeveelheid": "30",
    "Eenheid": "gram",
    "Ingredient": {
      "Ingredient_id": "2",
      "Naam": "Ragout",
      "Beschrijving": "Ragout (Nederlands-Nederlands) of vol-au-vent (Vlaams) is van oorsprong een gerecht dat bestaat uit stukjes gesneden vlees, gevogelte of vis in saus.",
      "Energie": "98",
      "Vetten": "5.5",
      "VerzadigdeVetten": "2.2",
      "KoolHydraten": "3.8",
      "Eiwitten": "8.3"
    }
  }]
}
```

The problem is that the Ingredient object is always NULL, even when I serialize the object itself.

The classes have been built very simplistic, using C# properties to store variables.
Normal lists of strings have worked fine previously, for example Instructies.

The class I'm trying to parse is Recept, which I do like this:
Recept recept = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
With JSON being the JSON input you can view above here.

Recept contains a few properties, which all work fine except for Benodigdheden.

```
[JsonProperty]
    public List<Benodigdheid> Benodigdheden
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    [JsonProperty]
    public List<string> Instructies
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    [JsonProperty]
    public int ReceptId
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string Naam
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    [JsonProperty]
    public ReceptType Type
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    [JsonProperty]
    public int GramPerPersoon
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public Recept(int id, string naam, ReceptType receptType, int gramPP, List<string> instructies, List<Benodigdheid> benodigdheden)
    {
        this.ReceptId = id;
        this.Naam = naam;
        this.Type = receptType;
        this.GramPerPersoon = gramPP;
        this.Instructies = instructies;
        getBenodigdHeden();
    }
```

The Benodigdheid class contains only 3 properties, which are:

```
 [JsonProperty]
    public Ingredient Ingredient
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    [JsonProperty]
    public int Hoeveelheid
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string Eenheid
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public Benodigdheid(Ingredient ingredient, int hoeveelheid, string eenheid)
    {
        this.Ingredient = ingredient;
        this.Hoeveelheid = hoeveelheid;
        this.Eenheid = eenheid;
    }
```

Then there is the last class named Ingredient (which means the same in english)

```
    [JsonProperty]
    public int Ingredient_id
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string Naam
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string Beschrijving
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    [JsonProperty]
    public float Energie
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    [JsonProperty]
    public float Vetten
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    [JsonProperty]
    public float VerzadigdeVetten{
        get;
        private set;
    }

    [JsonProperty]
    public float KoolHydraten
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    [JsonProperty]
    public float Eiwitten
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public Ingredient(int id, string naam, string beschrijving, float energie, float vetten, float verzadigde_vetten, float koolhydraten, float eiwitten) {
        this.Ingredient_id = id;
        this.Naam = naam;
        this.Beschrijving = beschrijving;
        this.Energie = energie;
        this.Vetten = vetten;
        this.VerzadigdeVetten = verzadigde_vetten;
        this.KoolHydraten = koolhydraten;
        this.Eiwitten = eiwitten;
    }
```

Comment: I tried to repro your problem in Linqpad, importing your Ingredient class and doing JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Ingredient>(json); where json is a string containing just an ingredient from your sample json, and everything worked fine, with or without the JsonProperty attributes (which are kind of useless). I think your problem resides elsewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to decorate your c# class with these attributes. from the json you posted, with [`http://json2csharp.com/`](http://json2csharp.com/), I've generated theses classe, which I think it is enough to you deserialize your json data.

```
public class Ingredient
{
    public string Ingredient_id { get; set; }
    public string Naam { get; set; }
    public string Beschrijving { get; set; }
    public string Energie { get; set; }
    public string Vetten { get; set; }
    public string VerzadigdeVetten { get; set; }
    public string KoolHydraten { get; set; }
    public string Eiwitten { get; set; }
}

public class Benodigdheden
{
    public string Hoeveelheid { get; set; }
    public string Eenheid { get; set; }
    public Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string ReceptId { get; set; }
    public string Naam { get; set; }
    public string GramPerPersoon { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public List<string> Instructies { get; set; }
    public List<Benodigdheden> Benodigdheden { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the output of the JSON website, I've figured it out.
My Array of Benodigdheden was named the Benodigdheden, while the array had items of the type Benodigdheid in it.
After renaming the Array to benodigdheid and the JSON too, it worked!
Thanks Felipe Oriani